# AHK Loop tracker and timer

Tags: autohotkey

I need assistance with creating a loop tracker, more specifically how many times the loop has been executed. Ex: 5 of 100; 23 of 100... and so on. 
The second thing is I need to see a message with the total time in ms that the loop takes to run a full cycle. Only the loop and not the rest of the function.

I have the following code:

```
WinActivate, Xbox Console Companion
Sleep, 100
Click, 1122, 880,0
Sleep, 100
Click, 1122, 880, Left, Down
Sleep, 100
Click, 1122, 880 Left, Up
Sleep, 1000
Loop, 200
{
Send, {Space Down}
Sleep, 85
Send, {Space Up}
Sleep, 7000
Send, {Space Down}
Sleep, 85
Send, {Space Up}
Sleep, 3000
Send, {Left Down}
Sleep, 85
Send, {Left Up}
Sleep, 85
Send, {Right Down}
Send, {r Down}
Sleep, 500
Send, {Right Up}{r Up}
Sleep, 23000
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`A_Index`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#loop) tells you the current iteration of the loop and [`A_TickCount`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#TickCount) can be used to time something. If the ~10ms precision isn't good enough, see the comment that's found on that link.

```
Loop
{
    time1 := A_TickCount
    Random, rand, 1000, 2000
    Sleep, % rand
    ToolTip, % "Iteration " A_Index " took ~" A_TickCount - time1 "ms."
}
```